# Animal Farm — silent protest?

Tags: george-orwell, animal-farm

Is *Animal Farm* by George Orwell a silent protest against the Russian Revolution? I am correcting an essay about *Animal Farm*, and someone called it a silent protest. I am not sure whether I should correct it. Just a brief overview of *Animal Farm* for those of you who have read it years ago and for those who never read it:

The book is a parallel to the Russian Revolution. Basically everything that happens is based on the USSR. Orwell wrote the book as a satire and mocking of the Russian Revolution. It was his way to protest what was going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "silent protest"?

Comment: So you're saying it's definitely protest but asking whether it's "silent protest"? This begs the question of what do you mean by silent. (A bestselling novel doesn't seem very "silent" to me ...)

Comment: Relevant - may actually be a possible duplicate https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/does-animal-farm-explicitly-state-anywhere-in-the-text-that-it-is-in-fact-a-po

Comment: @Randal'Thor, you'd say no then.

Comment: @MattThrower, it's not a duplicate. I am asking whether the phrase silent protests would be correct/logical.

Comment: @M.C. Thanks for clearing that up - the information in the answers may still be useful

Comment: It is VERY useful in general (nice response) but not for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

No, here is the definition of the term `silent protest`:

> Silent protest is an organized effort where the participants stay quiet to demonstrate disapproval. It is used as a form of civil disobedience and nonviolent resistance ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_protest)).

There is nothing *silent* about his protest.

You might be able to consider it [culture jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_jamming) but I'm not too familiar with the details so I'm not sure about that.